# Override bool ProcessKeyPreview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I use these following codes for handling the keydown in user control. But I want to know how I can to the same thing for user control for keypress.

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && (Keys)m.WParam == Keys.A)
    {
        messagebox.show("You have pressed A");
    }

    return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
}
```

I want to do this for keychar in keypress.

These codes just give me for example keys.A can't let me work for example keychar ='A'

Thanks in advance

Comment: A key press completes its cycle on key up.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I want to choose the char of the key like : if(e.keychar == 'A') in key press.

Answer (score 5):

A KeyPress event is very distinct from the KeyDown and KeyUp events.  You only get to override the KeyDown event handling with overrides like ProcessKeyPreview and ProcessCmdKey.

Such overrides only see the *virtual* key, it is the same on anybody's keyboard.  The default handling for KeyDown then sends the virtual key through code inside Windows that applies the specific keyboard layout that the user selected.  And if that produces a typing key, like "a" or "A" or I-don't-know-what on a Korean keyboard then *that* produces a KeyPress event.  Which is directly delivered to the control with the focus, you can only intercept it at the control by implementing an event handler for its KeyPress event.

The I-don't-know-what clause in the previous paragraph is the important part.  It is not in general meaningful to try to intercept typing keys.  Short from a distinction between "a" and "A", there are a good two billion potential users of your software that have never typed an "A" in their lives.  It isn't otherwise clear exactly *why* you are trying to do this so I can't suggest another approach.

Comment: I was talking about A just for an example. Maybe they press numpads buttons.